# R won't load installed package, citing errors that other packages must be unloaded first (and that they can't be unloaded)

Tags: r

I deeply don't understand the problem I am facing here and likely am not posting enough information, please be patient as I update/respond to comments... Thank you,

I've recently tried installing the package "metagenomeSeq" (URL: http://www.cbcb.umd.edu/software/metagenomeSeq ). This package uses its own installation routines, using the R script *biocLite* to install:

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("metagenomeSeq")
```

Installation is apparently successful:

```
> biocLite("metagenomeSeq")
BioC_mirror: https://bioconductor.org
Using Bioconductor 3.2 (BiocInstaller 1.20.1), R 3.2.5 (2016-04-14).
Installing package(s) ‘metagenomeSeq’
...
[snippped]
...
* installing *source* package ‘metagenomeSeq’ ...
** R
** data
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (metagenomeSeq)
```

However, attempting to load the packages yields the following:

```
> library("metagenomeSeq")
Loading required package: Biobase
Error in unloadNamespace(package) : 
  namespace ‘Biobase’ is imported by ‘DESeq2’, ‘genefilter’, ‘multtest’, ‘annotate’, ‘geneplotter’, ‘AnnotationDbi’ so cannot be unloaded
Error in library(pkg, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE, lib.loc = lib.loc,  : 
  Package ‘Biobase’ version 2.26.0 cannot be unloaded
```

I am using R v3.2.5  and Rstudio v099.491. Operating system: Ubuntu 14.04. Packages are:

```
library("scales")
library("ape")
library("ggplot2")
library("RColorBrewer")
library("igraph")
library("vegan")
library("gridExtra")
library("cowplot")
library("RAM")
library("plyr")
library("stringr")
library("gridExtra")
library("ggdendro")
library("reshape2")
library("xtable")
library("knitr")
library("phyloseq")
library("indicspecies")
```

Edit 1:

The package loads when I open up a fresh instance of R studio without loading any other packages first. Is it possible for an R's packages dependencies to have conflicts with other packages that require their dependencies to be unloaded? I've never come across this before.

Edit 2: Included packages I was using.

Comment: i cannot replicate your error when i run through your instructions. maybe you can try `detach(package:AnnotationDbi); detach(package:geneplotter); ... ; detach(package:BioBase)` before running `library(metagenomeSeq)`

Comment: I didn't disclose the other packages I was using, apologies: ` library("scales")
library("ape")
library("ggplot2")
library("RColorBrewer")
library("igraph")
library("vegan")
library("gridExtra")
library("cowplot")
#library("RAM")
library("plyr")
library("stringr")
library("gridExtra") library("reshape")
library("ggdendro")
library("reshape2")
library("xtable")
library("knitr")
library("phyloseq")
library("indicspecies")` ; however, I've found the offending package. Thanks though for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lazy fix: removing the libraries "reshape" and "RAM" (*RAM* depended on *reshape*) alleviated my problems.